# Custom Cookie/Session Function Not Working

Tags: php, function, session, cookies

I'm trying to write a simple function that check's if a cookie or session is set based on what you tell the function you want to check for. For some reason, if I tell the function that I want to check for a session, it still gives me the output from the conditions made in the 'cookie' block. Hopefully I explained this well enough. Anyways, if anyone could provide some assistance why this isn't working the way I want it to, that would be awesome.

```
function check($checkType, $name) {
  if ($checkType = 'cookie') {
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$name])) {
      echo "Cookie '" . $name . "' is set!<br>";
      echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$name];
      die();
    } else {
      echo "Cookie named '" . $name . "' is not set!";
      die();
    }
  } else if ($checkType = 'session') {
      if(isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
        echo "Session '" . $name . "' is set!<br>";
        echo "Value is: " . $_SESSION[$name];
        die();
      } else {
        echo "Session named '" . $name . "' is not set!";
        die();
      }
  }
}

//initiate function with parameters
check('session', 'loginStatus');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement, you're using the assignment operator (=). To check wether one value equals an other value, you should use the equal comparison operator (==).

```
if ($checkType == 'cookie') {
    // It's a cookie
} else if ($checkType == 'session') {
    // It's a session
}
```

You can read more about operators in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).